# How to check local IP address used by system.Net.Sockets.TcpClient?

Tags: .net, sockets, powershell

I would like use code like below

```
$c = "computername"
$p = PortNumber

#Create object for connecting to port on computer  
$tcpobject = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

#Connect to remote machine's port                
$connect = $tcpobject.BeginConnect($c,$p,$null,$null) 

#Configure a timeout before quitting  
$wait = $connect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne($TCPtimeout,$false)
```

to test destination port. The code will be run as a part of PowerShell script.

If is it possible to check what local IP address or (at least) local network adapter is used to initiate connection?

Answer (score 2):

*Once* the connection is established, you can access the [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [`Client`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.client(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which gives you a [`Socket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) that exposes the [`LocalEndpoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.localendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx) property, that can be cast to an [`IPEndpoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx) and interrogated.

But if you want this information *before* you make the connection, then no. No amount of pre-checking will let you know what state your network connectivity will be in at the later point at which you actually establish the connection.

Comment: I published PowerShell output to [PASTEBIN](pastebin.com/kHRVhKQ5). I really don't know how I can read that properties because they are not exposed (?). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is to check `netstat -n -o` while you are connected. It will show you the mapping between local and remote address